# Show that if $A$ and $B$ are non-empty separated sets, then $A \cup B$ is disconnected.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Show that if $A$ and $B$ are non-empty  separated sets, then $A \cup B$ is disconnected.

Attempt at solution:

Since $A$ and $B$ are separated, $A \cap \bar{B} = \emptyset$ and
$\bar{A} \cap B = \emptyset$.

Let $G = \bar{B}^c$ and $H = \bar{A}^c$.

Then $G$ and $H$ are open  and

$(A \cup B) \cap G = A$

and

$(A \cup B) \cap H = B$

are non-empty disjoint sets whose union is $A \cup B$. Now $G$ and $H$ form a disconnection of $A \cup B$, and so $A \cup B$ is diconnected.

Is my logic and solution valid? Thank you.

Comment: completely correct and valid proof. Just the formulation of the last sentence is flawed --- $G$,$H$ are not subsets of $A\cup B$.

Comment: @DanielValenzuela Thank you very much Daniel!